# How to crop Qml VideoOutput with Camera as the source?

Tags: qt, camera, qml, gstreamer, qtquick2

I want to crop the `VideoOutput` in QML with `Camera` as the source.
I want it like the `VideoCrop` element do in GStreamer.

Comment: Uhm... `fillMode: PreserveAspectCrop` doesn't do the job? It reads from the documentation: "the video is scaled uniformly to fill, cropping if necessary".

Comment: It is not an actual cropping. When we use  fillMode: PreserveAspectCrop  , it is not cropping the source . If we capture an image it will be same as the camera resolution